# Python mathmetical operation using a "for" loop not working

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to make a very basic  account money reduction system
The code I am using asks the user if he would like to buy the object which costs 200 bucks. The idea is that the $200 will be deducted from the variable named `total` but, for some reason, this is not working.

I do not know if it is possible to nest the For loop in an if statement.
Thank you for your time

```
total = 1500
print('Would you like to buy this item?')
print('It costs 100 bucks')
purchaseConfirm = input()
if purchaseConfirm == 'yes':
    for num in range(200):
        total = total-1   # Why is this thing not functioning???
        print(total)
        break
```

Comment: Is it not deducting anything or is it just substracting 1? Because the code inside the `for` is only executed once. Remove the `break`

Comment: Why do you need a `for` loop here at all? Just deduct 200 directly from the amount. Also, you have `break` in there which kills the `for` loop on its first iteration... so you only end up deducting $1.

Comment: What are you typing for your input?

Comment: Works for me (through the one iteration before `break`). Cannot reproduce.

Comment: Get rid of the `break`

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you need the for loop at all...

```
total = 1500
print('Would you like to buy this item?')
print('It costs 200 bucks')
purchaseConfirm = input()
cost = 200
if purchaseConfirm == 'yes':
  total = total - cost
  print(total)
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work :

```
total = 1500
print('Would you like to buy this item?')
print('It costs 100 bucks')
purchaseConfirm = raw_input()
if purchaseConfirm == 'yes':
    for num in range(200):
        total = total-1   # Why is this thing not functioning???
        print(total)
```

you should remove `break` to stay until the and of the loop...